# How to profile service running on kubernetes pod?

Tags: c++, kubernetes, profile

I want to profile service deployed on k8s cluster with perf/flame graph, but cannot install it in the pod. My program is written in C++, so unfotunately cannot profile with plugin `kubectl flame`.

```
root@mypod:/app# perf
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.4.0-1044

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke
    linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-gke
    linux-cloud-tools-gke
root@mypod:/app# apt-get install -y linux-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke'
root@mypod:/app# 
root@mypod:/app# apt-get install -y linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-1044-gke'
```

Or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The two most common "no modifications" tracing tools are bpftrace and systemtap. No idea if either will work on GKE's COS though, you would definitely need to do it from the actual VM inside the tools sandbox, not from inside the pod. Or could use gprof but that requires compiling the executable with profiling support active.

Answer (score 0):

If your k8s cgroupfs driver is not systemd, you can use perf with option '-G' with the container name. You can try to get info by perf doc.